# .reg file syntax to change a value

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

Okay, I am at my wits' end here. 
I want to create a .reg file which changes a value. I know how to do it manually, but however i search it i simply never find anything easily explaining the needed syntax to do it.

Change I want to apply

[image: Change I want to apply]

I want to change the displayed key to the value it already is changed to in the picture.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command]
```

What 's the last line I have to add to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This article has good info on how to make .REG files.

[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/310516)

Comment: So, you've forgotten to add a \" . It has to be 

     @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""

Comment: Oops. Should have tested it. It's now fixed.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I stumbled upon the link you gave me before, but i couldn't make sense of it, therefore I asked again.

Comment: YW. BTW it's easier than that. Apply the settings manually, and then use File > Export option in Regedit.exe, to create a .REG file. `@` denotes `(default)` entry.. `(standard)` in some non-English versions of Windows.